# Varchar to Datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert my Registrationdate(varchar)column in Table1 to Registrationdate(datetime)format in Table2. I need to use that in insertion code.

```
Insert Full_patient_reg (Patient_id,RegistrationDate,PatientName)
    select a.PATIENT_ID,a.REGISTRATIONDATE,a.PATIENTNAME from hinai_patient a
    where a.PATIENT_ID not in
    (select Patient_id from Full_patient_reg where a.PATIENT_ID=Patient_id)
```

It cause the error like 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Please suggest a code which act in insert code.

```
Dateformats (varchar)
2011-08-01 00:00:00
2000-11-16 07:39:44
2020-06-06 07:51:42.644
2020-05-26 06:55:38.08
```

Comment: What format are the dates in `hinai_patient`?

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: Date format is a very important question. Depending on where you are based you might also need to `set dateformat dmy`. Sql server is not very forgiving - sometimes you need to reformat it first.

Comment: Format types in that column '2011-08-01 00:00:00','2000-11-16 07:39:44','2020-06-06 07:51:42.644','2020-05-26 06:55:38.08'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple convert seems to be working fine:

```
select convert(datetime, RegistrationDate)
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1a848e4364b3e2991391e642f0adeef)**.